# Why is every frequently used standard C function automatically included in any C++ program?

Tags: c++, libraries

Functions like `malloc()` , `printf()` , `scanf()` , `rand()` , `time()` etc are ready for use in a program which hasn't included any of the related libraries (cstdlib , cstdio , ctime). Why? What is the point of including these libraries if their functions can be used without including them?

Comment: It might be because you included some other header file which in turn include these header files. If it happens in a system header file then it's an implementation detail that you should not rely on. *Always* explicitly include the header files you need.

Comment: I only included ``iostream`` nothing else. This header file is concerned with the input and the output stream. Does it use other header files?

Comment: Because it might need to use some of the functions you mention. Or other functions or structures declared or defined in some of those header files. Especially `<cstdio>` seems kind of relevant.

Comment: @zach Which compiler and which version ?

Comment: @NicolasDusart  G++ Version 7.5.0

Comment: includes are transitive, ie when a header you include does include other headers, then you can use stuff from that other header. It's not a feature but a defect, things will change with C++20 modules